# Конвертация *.raw с камеры GitUp G3 в *.tiff

Tags: c++, c, графика

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема. Требуется конвертация `*.RAW` файлов c  `4K NDVI CAMERA GitUp G3`.
Библиотека `libraw.h` с использованием `dcraw.c` работает с форматом камер `GitUp Git2`. Мой же файл она просто не распознает и выводит:

> Unsupported file format or not RAW file

Так же пробовал с утилитой `raw2dng`, но и там тоже происходит

> Unsupported file format.

Помогите пожалуйста найти способ конвертации данного `*.RAW` файла. Прикрепляю файл (https://yadi.sk/d/sdHHY4jw3aj4Ga).
За ранее благодарю!

Comment: Используйте `libraw`, [описание изменений](https://github.com/obache/nsrc/commit/65f2db51db78b25e2c1db7908c4eae75648e685b)

Comment: @NewView, забрал последнюю версию - у меня не завелось (ОС: macOS).

Comment: @NewView, я использовал ее (последнюю сборку), о чем писал выше. Он не распознает этот файл.

Comment: @user9422776, скажите пожалуйста, что такое ```Git G3``` и ```4K NVDI CAMERA```?

Comment: @isnullxbh,
https://www.4klens.co/products/4k-gitup-g3-duo-camera-pro-packing

Переделывается мелкосерийно из action камеры путем замены объектива и снятия IR фильтра

Comment: @user9422776, спасибо, понял. А что тогда значит выражение `c  4K NDVI CAMERA с GitUp G3` - я про два предлога 'с'?

Comment: @isnullxbh, опечатался. Файлов c  `4K NDVI CAMERA GitUp G3`.

Comment: @user9422776, и еще один вопрос, пожалуйста, когда я исправил Вас - зачем Вы заново исправили на ошибочный вариант?

Comment: @isnullxbh, требуется (что?) конвертация (чего?) файлов (откуда?) с камеры (с какой?) 4K NDVI CAMERA GitUp G3. Не понимаю ваших вопросов

Comment: @user9422776, ну да, а тут какой вспомогательный вопрос зададите - ```c 4K NDVI CAMERA с GitUp G3```?

Comment: @isnullxbh, ответил вам выше о том, что одна "с" лишняя и продемонстрировал, как должно было быть. Это была опечатка.

Comment: @user9422776, тогда вернитесь на 4 сообщения выше и перечитайте вопрос ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Для этого я добавил поддержку камеры в классах библиотеки libraw:

> libraw_cxx.cpp
>
> dcraw_common.cpp
>
> dcraw.c

Вот параметры:

```
{24000000, 4000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x94, 0, 0, "GITUP", "G3DUO 4:3"},
{18016000, 4000, 2250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x94, 0, 0, "GITUP", "G3DUO 16:9"}
```

После этого проект был скомпилирован, и теперь dcraw_emu может преобразовывать raw в tiff для этой камеры!